# THEOS for iOS returning make error

Tags: ios, objective-c, makefile, jailbreak, theos

I recently got THEOS for iOS, so that I could try my hand at making a small jailbreak app or tweak. I found a tutorial of how to 'make' a Hello World program and followed it and everything worked fine.

When I went to 'make' the program from the command line, I got this error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwNlm.jpg

Does anyone know what the error means/how to solve it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Need much more info. What tutorial are you following, and what is THEOS?

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo THEOS is a tool to create iPhone apps (specifically jail broken ones) without Xcode. [link] (https://github.com/DHowett/theos)

Answer (score 0):

You get this error when there isn't an SDK in *theos/sdks*. You have to retrieve one and put in that folder renaming it from *iPhoneOS* to ***iPhoneOSX.X.sdk***.

- See here for getting one: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Retrieving_SDKs
- See here your error: http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Setup#Also_for_Linux_and_iOS_.28and_other_operating_systems_other_than_Mac_OS_X.29:_Retrieving_SDKs